# How create n independent lists in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a user input module where: when user type - input 4 5 6
then create a list and 1 line input from [1:3] store in that list and when they type print then the list should be print - [4,5,6].
I am done with this step but when the user again types inset then I want to create a new list that stores data and on second print show new independent list.

ex:-

insert 4 5 6

print

insert 7 8 9

print

----output----

[4,5,6]

[7,8,9]

```
l = []
for i in range(int(input())):
    a = input().split()[:]
    if a[0] == 'insert':
        a1 = a[1] #index 
        a2 = a[2] #object
        a1 = int(a1)
        a2 = int(a2)
        l.insert(a1, a2)
    elif a == 'print':
        pass
print(l)
```

Comment: for loop range is the no of steps user perform

Comment: the code is doing what you asked it to do, it's building a list of lists with your call to .insert() I guess you just want/need to print the last list of the lists, or somehow select the correct one to print, so only a part of l but not fully print(l) !?

Comment: This question could be improved by improving the formatting and using more clear grammar. Currently it takes some work to understand what your desired result is, and I'm still not sure I've understood correctly.

Comment: Basically I want a program which ask for input when user enter - insert 4 5 6 then it will create a list of [4,5,6] and when type print then print first list. And then again user give input - insert 7 8 9. It will create another list [7,8,9] and again input get print then print last list - 789

Comment: @codeoneb You should edit your post to include any further explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code is as below:

```
ls = []
while True:
    line = input("Type your command:")
    if line.split()[0].lower() == "insert":
        ls.append([i for i in line.split()[1:]]) # If you want integer, use `eval(i)` in list comprehension
    elif line.split()[0].lower() == "print":
        print(ls[-1])
    else:
        print("Command is not supported.")
        break
```

And my outputs while running:

```
Type your command:insert 4 5 6
Type your command:print
['4', '5', '6']
Type your command:insert 7 8 9
Type your command:print
['7', '8', '9']
Type your command:hello
Command is not supported.
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while True:
    a=input("Enter the numbers: ")
    l=a.split(" ")
    print(l)
    if(input ("Do you want to continue(y/n):").lower()!='y'):
        break
```

Comment: I read this before you formatted it, and had the awful idea that this could be done as a one-liner: `main = lambda: print(input("Enter the numbers: ").split(" ")) or (False if ('y' != input("Do you want to continue(y/n): ")) else main())`